# How to get from Switzerland to Nashik, Maharashtra, India by public transport

Tags: public-transport, india

The title says it all. I'd like to know what my options are to get from Switzerland to Nashik, Maharashtra, India by public transport. The only option I could find was to fly from Zurich to Mumbai and then take one of the slow trains. Are there any other, in particular faster, options?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean trains, busses, airplanes, ferries etc, by public transport correct?

Comment: Yes! (15 chars)

Comment: Take one of the fast trains instead of the slow trains ? (sorry, bad jokes); 
Me think the bottleneck is in India; what mode of transports exists between Mumbai and Nashik ? train, bus, cars ?

Comment: Well, even the fast trains seem to be kinda slow compared to the trains I'm used to, that's why I called them slow too.

Comment: I couldn't find any other connection in India. But maybe it's possible to fly in to Nashik (maybe from Dehli), even though I couldn't find an airport in Nashik.

Comment: Did Rome2Rio offer any interesting options?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nashik#Get_in ? There also seem to be frequent buses but their travel time given as 4-5h probably equally slow as the train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of answers from people who actually know something about India: I assume you have already checked [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Switzerland/Nashik) on this and found that basically you can fly to Mumbai (or Pune or Aurangabad, in that order of preference) and then take the train. What I found suggests that this is your best option.

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Mumbai/Nashik) and [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nashik#Get_in) list buses as an alternative, however travel time is given as 6h or 4-5h and that does not beat the train.

An airport is not listed on Wikivoyage and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhinagar_Airport) reveals that the Nashik airport now essentially is an army base. There is [another airport in Ozar close by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozar_Airport) with a new passenger terminal but there seem to be no flights going there yet and Google reviews affirm my view that it is not yet in operation (at least for passenger flights).